# Emberjs - Rendering gallery image one by one

Tags: ember.js

My problem is a bit odd because I don't understand how this can't work.
I have a list of item display on my page, and whem the user click on one, this will trigger an action event that will also receive the product that was clicked (object).

When the action handler is triggered, I'm calling `loadGallery` (see below) that should normally render my images one by one inside my template.
SelectedItem is a property of my controller.

```
   loadGallery: function( device ) {
        var that = this;
        var images = device.images.map( function( item, idx ) {
            return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function( resolve ) {
                if ( item.url ) {
                    resolve( item );
                }
                else {
                    resolve( that.imageStore.readImage( that, item ) );
                }
            })
            .then( function( image ) {
                var imageURLs = device.imageURLs.slice( 0, device.imageURLs.length );
            imageURLs[idx] = image.url;
            //that.set('selectedItem.imageURLs.'+idx, image.url );
            that.set('selectedItem.imageURLs', imageURLs );
            that.set('selectedItem.images.' + idx, image );
            return image;
            });
        });
        return Ember.RSVP.Promise.all( images );
    },
```

What I'm doing here, is that I'm replacing every URL inside the array `device.images` by an objet like this : `{ key: 'someKey', url: 'url' }`

But my template doesn't refresh when it goes there..

The only way that I manage to make it work, its waiting for all the images are done loaded and refresh the property like that :

```
return Ember.RSVP.Promise.all( images ).then(function(imgs){
            that.set('selectedItem.images', imgs);
        });
```

Why this is working but not the one by one image ?

[edit] Here is my template :

```
<div class="gallery">
    {{#each img in selectedItem.images}}
        {{#if img.url}}
            <div href="{{unbound img.url}}" class="gallery-item" style="background-image: url({{unbound img.url}})"></div>
        {{else}}
            <div class="gallery-item" style="background-image: url(images/loading.png)"></div>
        {{/if}}
    {{/each}}
</div>
```

Here is the readImage function :

```
  this.readImage = function( controller, key ) {
        var that = this;
        return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function( resolve ) {
            controller.store.findQuery( 'image', { key: key })
            .then(function( image ) {
                var result = undefined;
                var content = image.content[0];
                var data = content && content._data;
                if( data ) {
                    if ( iOSVersion()[0] >= 7 || isBlobSupported() ) {
                        result = {
                            key: key,
                            url: dataURIToURL( data.base64, key )
                        }
                    } else {
                        result = {
                            key: key,
                            url: data.base64
                        }

                    }
                }
                resolve( result );
            })
            .catch(function( e ) {
                console.log( e );
                resolve();
            });
        });
    };
```

Comment: Is this line essentially doing nothing though?  is it setting the property to what it already is? . I'm going to guess yes

Comment: Well, if it was working, I should be able to see the result in my template. So, I assume that is not doing anything. Yes it's setting the property to what it already is, like an update, modifying the array inside my object.

Comment: Actuallys this line, `device.images.set( idx+'', image );`, or whatever is watching each image, is the problem.  Can you show your template? or computed property that's dependent on it?

Comment: I have added the template to the main post, but device is just the object that I got from the template when the user click on a product in the list of object displayed with an `{{#each}}`

Comment: can you show what `that.imageStore.readImage( that, item )` does also?

Comment: I have updated the question for you. basically, its generating an object with 2 items in it, and this is this object that will be added in the array instead of the simple item.

Answer (score 0):

Ember ignores sets of the same value (array, object of the same reference).

The reason it works in your promise all, is it creates a new array, and Ember sees that as different.

This also looks like you are attempting to index set an item in a collection.  Despite this functioning properly (some hidden black magic of Ember I'd never seen) it doesn't properly notify Ember that the item has changed, example http://emberjs.jsbin.com/cevimara/1/edit

```
device.images.set( idx+'', image );
```

you might try switching to replace (http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ArrayProxy.html#method_replace)

```
device.images.replace(idx, 1, [image]);
```

Example: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/cevimara/1/edit

Comment: I should create a new array inside my map, populate it, and setting `selectedItem` after every image loaded?

Comment: I have found an other way to do this using this : `that.set('selectedItem.images.' +idx, image);` But its not working the first time you click, you have to click on an other product and click again on the previous one to have the images load.. ?!?

Comment: try using replace instead of set on the array.

Comment: It's not working unfortunately.. But this `that.set('selectedItem.images.' +idx, image);` is half working. When I select product1 its doesn't load the gallery, I select product2 same problem, but when I select again product1 its working. I don't understand...

Comment: I have edited the loadGallery function, I had no need to use the device.images.set.. because I could just replace every item of my array with the object. But its still only displaying after I select the product twice..
I have check with the ember debugger, and its seems that my selectedItem.images array is filled correctly with the object, but not displayed on the template.

Comment: Do you think you could set up a dummy example using emberjs.jsbin.com?  I'm not sure if I can properly debug without watching it go through anymore..

Comment: I manage to do something that should be the same : http://emberjs.jsbin.com/yodijuso/4/ However I don't understand why my  function isn't called in the jsbin.. In the jsbin you can see properly that I want to modify every item of the images array one by one to the template would be refresh for every image.

Comment: loadGallery shouldn't be in the actions hash ;)  I'm still playing with it, working through the code, http://jsbin.com/yodijuso/5/edit

Comment: Ahhh yeah that's why, I'm sorry, I'm not use to this indentation hehe. I have found a workaround, but I really would like to know why it's not working... (I have put the workaround in the question)

Comment: It looks like it's updating immediately using the replace, http://jsbin.com/yodijuso/5/edit

Comment: How is this possible ? you don't even update the `selectedItem` property in the `loadGallery` function?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55970/discussion-between-supermarco-and-kingpin2k).